# WSDL field name differs when sending request

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm sending requests to SOAP WS from Java project.
By wsdl I have generated required sources using:

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> 
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>3.1.6</version>
```

WSDL that I use has following fields:

```
<xs:complexType name="HitOffers">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Comment" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Offers" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfHitOfferBase"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="HitOffers" nillable="true" type="tns:HitOffers"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfHitOfferBase">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="HitOfferBase" nillable="true"
                    type="tns:HitOfferBase"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfHitOfferBase" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfHitOfferBase"/>
<xs:complexType name="HitOfferBase">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsExported" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsRequired" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Order" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Status" nillable="true" type="tns:OfferStatus"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So, in the request I want to see something like:

```
<b:Offers xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCSBank.Common.Model.Applications.Offers">
    <c:Comment i:nil="true"/>
    <c:Offers>
        <c:HitOfferBase
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCSBank.Common.Model.Applications.PreCollection.Offers.Mail"
                i:type="d:PreCollectionMailOffer">
            <c:Id>xxx</c:Id>
            <c:IsExported>false</c:IsExported>
            <c:IsRequired>true</c:IsRequired>
            <c:Order>1</c:Order>
            <c:Status i:nil="true"/>
            <d:Mail xmlns:e="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCSBank.Common.Model.Applications.Offers.Blocks">
                <c:BlockResult i:nil="true"/>
                <c:IsWithClarify>false</c:IsWithClarify>
                <c:Name>xxx</c:Name>
                <c:OriginalValue>mail123@yandex.ru</c:OriginalValue>
                <e:Value i:nil="true"/>
            </d:Mail>
        </c:HitOfferBase>
    </c:Offers>
</b:Offers>
```

But my request looks a bit different:

```
<ns28:Offers>
<ns10:ArrayOfHitOfferBase>
    <ns10:HitOfferBase xsi:type="ns26:PreCollectionMailOffer">
        <ns10:Id>425100970</ns10:Id>
        <ns10:IsExported>false</ns10:IsExported>
        <ns10:IsRequired>true</ns10:IsRequired>
        <ns10:Order>1</ns10:Order>
        <ns20:MailOfferBlock>
            <ns10:IsWithClarify>false</ns10:IsWithClarify>
            <ns10:Name>??????? email</ns10:Name>
            <ns10:OriginalValue xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns20:MailOfferBlock>
    </ns10:HitOfferBase>
</ns10:ArrayOfHitOfferBase>
```

As you can see we got **ArrayOfHitOfferBase** tag name instead of **Offers**, which is wrong (The **Comment** param is null so there is no tag).  My generated sources are fine. Top class **HitOffers** source looks fine:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "HitOffers", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCSBank.Common.Model.Applications.Offers", propOrder = {
    "comment",
    "offers"
})
public class HitOffers {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Comment", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCSBank.Common.Model.Applications.Offers", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<String> comment;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Offers", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCSBank.Common.Model.Applications.Offers", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfHitOfferBase> offers;
```

As you see the field **@XmlElementRef** attribute **name = "Offers"** which is right. Can anybody help me to understand the reathon of the problem and how to get rid of this wrong naming?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Sorry for grammar mistakes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. `cxf-codegen-plugin` creates ObjectFactory class containing methods for creating WSDL objects as well as JAXBElement objects. So I was creating

> ArrayOfHitOfferBase arrayOfHitOfferBase1 =
>   factoryData.createArrayOfHitOfferBase()

instean of

> JAXBElement hitOffersOffers =
>   factoryData.createHitOffersOffers(arrayOfHitOfferBase)

Unfortinately `HitOffers` object after being generated with plugin accepts `ArrayOfHitOfferBase` as well as `JAXBElement<ArrayOfHitOfferBase>`